# Spring 3 @PropertySource cannot find properties file in Wildfly 8 module

Tags: java, spring, wildfly-8

I'm trying to load a properties file using Spring's @PropertySource annotation. The properties file is stored in a Wildfly 8 module. The error message that I'm getting is:

```
class path resource [campaigner.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here's the Java code, which is used by the application's services.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:campaigner.properties")
class ServiceConfigImpl implements ServiceConfig
{
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean(name = "serviceConfig")
  public ServiceConfig getServiceConfig()
  {
    return new ServiceConfigImpl(this.env);
  }
}
```

Here's my jboss-deployment-structure.xml, which I'm putting in the META-INF directory of my .ear file.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
  <deployment> 
    <dependencies> 
      <module name="com.dr_dee_sw.campaigner" /> 
    </dependencies> 
  </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I've also put a MANIFEST.MF file in the META-INF directory

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_71-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Dependencies: com.dr_dee_sw.campaigner
```

Here's my module file, which I've put in WILDFLY_HOME\modules\com\dr_dee_sw\campaigner\main directory, along with the campaigner.properties file

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.dr_dee_sw.campaigner">
  <resources> 
    <resource-root path="."/> 
  </resources> 
</module>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page led me to the answer: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/jboss-as-7-classloading-explained.html. My jboss-deployment-structure.xml was wrong. I have an EJB-JAR file inside the EAR file and that needs to be the focus of that file. So, I had to switch from using <deployment> to <sub-deployment> as shown below.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
  <sub-deployment name="campaigner-service.jar">
    <dependencies> 
      <module name="com.dr_dee_sw.campaigner" /> 
    </dependencies> 
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```